# How can I advanced search for tweets on engine with the word 'casa' but not having 'câsa' results included?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I try this method:

```
casa -câsa
```

But that way it excludes the `casa` without accents too, then the search returns blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Twitter flattens-out all accented latin letters and treats them the same, so...
`a` = `á` = `â` = `à` = `ä` = `ā` = `ã` = `å`.

One possible way to clean a little bit your search results is to use Twitter's advanced search language operator `lang:[xx]` in negation `-lang:[xx]`, where `[xx]` represents the [2 letter ISO language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) of the languages which might be using that particular letter (assuming you wish to filter-out from the results).

In your example, the letter `Ââ` (circumflex) [is used by the following languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%82): Sami, Romanian, Vietnamese, French, Frisian, Portuguese, Turkish, Walloon and Welsh. Assuming you wish to filter-out results from these specific languages, your Twitter search query would look like this:

```
"casa" -lang:se -lang:ro -lang:vi -lang:fr -lang:fy -lang:pt -lang:tr -lang:wa -lang:cy
```

[try it...](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22casa%22%20-lang%3Ase%20-lang%3Aro%20-lang%3Avi%20-lang%3Afr%20-lang%3Afy%20-lang%3Apt%20-lang%3Atr%20-lang%3Awa%20-lang%3Acy&src=typed_query&f=live)

Alternatively, you can use the same `lang:[xx]` operator to limit Twitter's  search results to one specific language (for example - English):

```
"casa" lang:en
```

[try it...](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22casa%22%20lang%3Aen&src=typed_query&f=live)

This might not be a water-tight solution but it can reduce a lot of false positives.

Finally, you should keep in mind that [Twitter is not guaranteeing accuracy](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2015/evaluating-language-identification-performance) in their machine-identification of languages.